# Store the ID Numbers of the Last Uploaded Images Inside an Array?

Tags: php, mysql

**The Script:**

```
$desired_width = 110;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array
        $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/gallerysite/multiple_image_upload/uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");  //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

        $new_image_name = md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];
        $target_path = $target_path . $new_image_name;//set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';

                $tqs = "INSERT INTO images (`original_image_name`, `image_file`, `date_created`) VALUES ('" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i] . "', '" . $new_image_name  . "', now())";
                $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs);


                /*
                 * At this spot right here with the variable "$new_image_name".
                 */


                // Goes over to create the thumbnail images.
                $src = $target_path;
                $dest = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/gallerysite/multiple_image_upload/thumbs/" . $new_image_name;

                make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width);


            } else {//if file was not moved.
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

This script also uses java script for multiple image upload.

I am looking to select the ID numbers from the ID column of the ***last*** uploaded images.

It should store the ID numbers inside an array.

***For Example:***

```
    // It stores the ID numbers of the hashtags inside an array.
    $hashlist = join ("','", array_map(array($dbc,'real_escape_string'),$hashtags));

    $tqs = "SELECT `id` FROM `hashtags` WHERE `hashtag` IN ('$hashlist')";
    $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

    $fetch_array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tqr)){
        $fetch_array[] = $row['id'];
    }

    // This implodes the array with the ID numbers into a string.
   $fetch_array = implode(", ", $fetch_array);

    // The previously created thread gets its "hashtag_id" column updated with the hashtag ID numbers.
    // The hashtag ID numbers are separated by commas.
    $tqs = "UPDATE thread SET `hashtag_id` = '" . $fetch_array . "' WHERE `id` = '" . $the_insert_id . "'";
    $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
```

I use this script to select the ID numbers from the hashtags table. It then stores them inside an array, then I use the "explode()" function on the array, after that the script stores the ID numbers inside of a column in the table "hashtags".

If I use this example on the scenario with the images then I am getting errors.
For example:

```
Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallerysite\multiple_image_upload\upload.php on line 52

Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallerysite\multiple_image_upload\upload.php on line 52
Array ( )
```

I am looking to solve the scenario with the images in this manner too.
The ID numbers of the ***last*** uploaded image should get selected, then get stored inside an array, so I can insert the ID numbers (separated by commas) inside a column of a table.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I am wondering why this is not used in the tutorials or "also" in the examples of the documentation of PHP. I have reading the tutorials and the documentation of PHP and I did not think there would be issues with this. Thanks for the links.

Comment: It's because 90% of the tutorials out there are, unfortunately, garbage. If they're not artifacts from the 1990s, they're based on them. I'm consistently appalled at the low quality of PHP tutorials, and even worse, the sorts of things they're forcing people to learn in school, like subjecting them to `mysql_query`.